# Prove that a function is greater than another after som point.

Tags: calculus, functions

I have two functions:

$$ f(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$ and:

$$ g(x) = \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x+1}$$

is there a way to prove that:

$$ g(x) < f(x)$$

for all $x$ after some point?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: $g(x) = f(x+1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the function $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$ then this is decreasing for $x>e$ ($f'(x)=\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$) so $f(x+1)<f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!